# Can we modify Gitlab CI/CD variable value using python

Tags: python-3.x, gitlab-ci

I am trying to see if its possible to modify or update Gitlab  CI/CD variable value using python ?

Comment: Gitlab cicd variable are just environment variable automatically set by gitlab. You can edit them they way you usually change an environment variable's value. Can you provide more information about what you are trying to do?

Comment: @NicolasB. this is what I try to do now and it doesn't seem easy to do.